# Powershell pass user input to icacls

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently I am writing a powershell script to automate some security measures and I have run into a small problem.

```
icacls myDirectory /inheritance:r /grant:r 'Administrators:F' $myGroup + ':F'
```

will fail as $myGroup gets tacked onto the `icacls` call and fails to properly add permissions to both groups.  This is on Windows 7 and from the context of powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parser sees `$myGroup + ':F'` as three individual arguments.  You can use either:

```
"${myGroup}:F"
```

or

```
($myGroup + ':F')
```

to provide this info to the parser as one argument.

Comment: The second one works, the first one fails.  Once you make that change I will accept this as the answer

Comment: Looks like `:` can be a legal part of a variable name, so you have to delineate the variable name part of the string using `{` and `}`.

Comment: Hmm, can't put `:` in a variable name AFAICT.  Wonder why then the parser can't figure this out and not requires the curly braces?